# Copy SharePoint pages to a page library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

There are some sites in our site collection which is not used any more. After some discussion we decided to move the pages in the site to a newly created page library along with the images uploaded in the base site. How to i do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can copy your pages to another location in the same site collection, just follow the below steps:

- Go to **Site Settings**
- Under Site Administration click on **Content and structure**.
- You can now see a file structure of your site.
- look for the  Pages Library  that your pages are in.
- Check the check boxs beside the pages you want to Copy.
- Click on **Actions**
- Click on **Copy**
- Select the Destination then click on **OK**

Comment: copy is disabled for pages library under content and structure

Comment: @Rinu from Content and structure page it should be enabled, if you may , add a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the pages are all checked in, then copy should be enabled for pages library under content and structure.

Besides, you can use open with Explorer.

Navigate to the pages library->Open with Explorer->copy the pages and paste them to the destination page library's Explorer.

[image]